# Laravel websockets caching event class and doesn't reload changes

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-events, laravel-websockets

I cannot change the channel name in the event class. Every change I make in the class is not loaded. (I am using [laravel-websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets))

`/app/Events/BroadcastingModelEvent`

```
class BroadcastingModelEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
    {
        use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    
        public $message;
    
        public function __construct($message)
        {
            $this->message = $message;
        }
    
        public function broadcastOn()
        {
            return new Channel('test');
        }
    
    }
```

`/routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('test', function () {
    event(new App\Events\BroadcastingModelEvent('Test'));
    return "Event has been sent!";
});
```

`VueComponent`

```
Echo.channel('test')
                .listen('BroadcastingModelEvent', (e) => {
                     console.log(e);
                });
```

**So this code works, I receive the event in the console.log everything is ok.**

But if I change `return new Channel('something');` and `Echo.channel('something')` it stops working.

I tried `php artisan route:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan event:clear` and nothing works.I stopped the `php artisan websockets:serve` process and restarted it. That class only works with the 'test' name I first gave and nothing else.

I cannot figure out where is it caching the class because any change I make in `BroadcastingModelEvent` is not reflected.

Comment: you need to create channel in `channels.php` then in event you can use it

Comment: but with `test` name works without any entry in channels.php. Anyway I added `Broadcast::channel('something', function () {
    return true;
});` still is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone facing this issue, you need to restart the queue worker process when you edit the events.

Comment: this is works for me